# Ripple affect in material ui to fill up the button with a different color

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am using material ui for react. So When the user clicks on the button(from material ui), there is a ripple effect seen, but it fades away soon, I would want that the ripple effect fill up the button with a different color.

Please give suggestions how could this be achieved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the TouchRipple component's [code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/internal/TouchRipple.js#L16), it's got a prop called `color`. All material-ui components use the TouchRipple for the ripple effect. Now you want to control the color of this prop for Buttons. Material UI offers [several](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/flat-button) different kinds of buttons. You can follow the code of the button you want to use, you'll notice they use EnhancedButton which then uses TouchRipple. EnhancedButton [exposes a prop](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/internal/EnhancedButton.js#L64) call `touchRippleColor` which can be used to specify the color of the ripple effect.

Comment: so you mean I should just use EnhancedButton and then use the `touchRippleColor` with it?

Comment: No, read the code of the kind of button you are using. Understand if/how it sends the value of touchRippleColor prop to EnhancedComponent. E.g. the FlatButton expose this as `rippleColor` prop, so depending on which kind of Button you are using the prop name may be different.

Comment: I am using the RaisedButton, it has got `rippleStyle`, in which I can set the color and opacity of the ripple effect, but it just styles the ripple effect.

I can't fill up the button with the same color. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: So you need your button to have a color initially, but then when the ripple effect executes, you need to change the button color to something else as the ripple completes. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yep, as in the ripple effect fills the button with that color

Comment: Not sure how to do that without hacking your way into Material-UI. Check in their Github issues forum for some tips. Good luck.

Comment: Sure man, appreciate the help. If I find any luck, I'll let you know